# What is commonly used for features when classifying images with nearest neighbor algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, nearest-neighbor

If one wanted to perform the K-nearest-neighbors algorithm to do classification on images, how are features extracted from the images?  What are the easiest, most effective methods?

Answer (score 3):

Great [tutorial](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/eccv10-tutorial/) on feature learning for image classification

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the exact problems.

For general problems, I'd always start with either some form of texture features (if you want image-level features) or local features (such as SURF).

The [documentation for mahotas](http://packages.python.org/mahotas/features.html) has a bit of an intro into this.

Answer (score 0):

There are many features you can use... but as already said it depends on the case and what you get from your segmentations...

you can classify from:

```
color
rectangularity
circularity
area
diameter
circumference
...
```

these are just a few but should be easy to calculate once you segmented your objects...

Hope that helps...